# Azure API Get Package availablity as Management Cmdlets

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

We had to take backup of existing Azure deployment from a running Azure role. Azure REST API has a method [Get Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx) to carry out this operations but i cannot find this method on Management Cmdlet.

Here is [list of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841) that are available through Azure Cmdlets

Does it mean not all methods on REST API are exposed as cmdlets? Also do we need to write custom code to post the request to REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks like the `GetPackage` operation is not available through the Powershell Cmdlets. In that case you will need to implement this yourself, but you can start with the assembly which allows you to call the Service Management API using C# (or Powershell). This library is [available on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library). Here is how you can get the package using C#:

```
var mgmt = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel(mycert);
IAsyncResult result = mgmt.BeginGetPackage(subscriptionId, serviceName, deploymentName, containerUri, overwriteExisting, (ar) =>
{
    // Handle EndGetPackage...
}, null);
```

Comment: Having trouble with the API (or even calling directly) - Error 400 Bad request - Parameter value 'https://something.blob.core.windows.net/somecontainer' specified for parameter 'ContainerUriString' is invalid. Does anyone have ideas why?